# android, No Network Exception

Tags: android, exception

I have a searchbox for searching locations in a google maps.

mi question is: what is the exception to handle when the user does not have acces to the internet(or the connection fails) for searching a location?

thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good approach ... 
you should always check internet connection before. use:

```
  public static boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo == null) {
            // no internet connection
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }
```

and don't forget permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: thx for the answer ,but what happens when the connection fails when the user clicks on the search button?